# Android: Swipe-able Fragment "onTabSelected"

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-fragments, tabs

I have a 2 fragments, fragment adapter, sliding tab layout, sliding tab strip and main activity.

How do i change the action bar text when i change tab like when user select tab1 the action bar text is home and tab 2 action bat text is profile.

also how do i change to tab text to icon.

for my *final year project* please help thanks :D

Guide for the sliding tab: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

it crashed when i add

```
 getActivity().getActionBar().setTitile("required title as per
 fragment");
```

in the fragment @Override onResume

> LogCat error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

Comment: So, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

In `onResume()` of each fragment you can get actionbar like `getActivity().getActionBar().setTitile("required title as per fragment");`

i hope this will solve you problem

Comment: it crashed when i added the code to my fragment.
Logcat error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: what is your theme is it noActionbar

Comment: my theme have a AppTheme.DarkActionBar